# Parse Error: Clients aren't allowed to perform the find operation on the role collection

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, mlab

I've been migrating my parse.com backend to use ParseServer with Heroku and MongoLab. However, after the migration I now get the error: "Clients aren't allowed to perform the find operation on the role collection" whenever I try to search a role. It would appear that post migration I can no longer search roles client side. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: This is not a bug. This behaivor came with last update. Follow [this issue](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/1718)  for discussion and more details.